# Filtering by comparing 2 rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
item consumerID userID
A        1        1
B        1        1
C        1        2
D        2        2
E        2        2
F        2        3
G        4        4
H        5        6
```

I want to get all items where consumerID is not like userID grouped by userID

I am currently doing it programatically in PHP but I wonder if it'd be possible to do this with SQL directly. I am using MariaDB.

Desired output:

```
item consumerID userID
C        1        2
F        2        3
H        5        6
```

Comment: Hint : `WHERE` clause (i.e. `consumerId <> userId`).

Comment: What happened to your earlier question?  Did you delete it?

Comment: This looks like a very simple query is there some hidden tripwire? And why the mention of grouped by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you simply looking for "not equals"?

```
select t.*
from t
where consumerId <> userId;
```